# The app store download could not start because it has already been downloaded too many times

Tags: macos, high-sierra, install, bootable-disk

I wanted to reinstall mac on my Apple Macbook Air 2017.

I restarted my Mac while holding down Command+R and Erased the disk in "Disk Utility".

I clicked on "Reinstall macOS" but I was having some internet issues yesterday so it failed a couple of times. I tried again and again but it was failing.

My internet is fixed today but I'm going back to the same section "Reinstall macOS" but it shows me an error:

"The app store download could not start because it has already been downloaded too many times"

Is there any way to download the original factory version of Mac or to fix this problem so that I can download it again from the internet.

I saw many options which suggest creating a bootable USB drive but unfortunately, I don't have access to any other mac system.

Answer (score 2):

I finally installed MacOS Catalina.

Previously I was pressing `Command + R` during startup.

I Finally pressed `Command + Option + R` and it installed Catalina on my Mac.